# Is it possible to use physics or other form of non-canonical reasoning to study functions?

Tags: probability, geometry, reference-request, soft-question, physics

It is well-known (see, for example, the books *New Horizons in geometry*, *Maxima and minima without calculus* and *The Mathematical Mechanic*) that it is possible to use some forms of "physical reasoning", "geometric reasoning", or "probabilistic reasoning" or otherwise non-canonical arguments to find minima and maxima of some functions or to solve some problems that normally require calculus.

> Are there such methods to calculate limits, find derivatives, or
>   verify the continuity of a function? Could you provide some examples?

Comment: I have a brief (less than one page) item to appear in the _American Mathematical Monthly_ that shows how to differentiate the tangent and secant functions by using elementary geometry without any of the usual stuff about limits or things like product and quotient rules, or prior knowledge of derivatives of other functions.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Congratulations for your paper :). Is there a preprint available on the ArXiv or on your webpage?

Comment: I don't know the _Monthly_'s policy on public circulation of preprints.  Does anyone?

Comment: what about ballistic trajectories, free falling and brachistochrones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$% Predefined Typography
 \newcommand{\paren} [1]{\left({#1}\right)}
 \newcommand{\bparen}[1]{\bigg({#1}\bigg)}
 \newcommand{\brace} [1]{\left\{{#1}\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bbrace}[1]{\bigg\{{#1}\bigg\}}
 \newcommand{\floor} [1]{\left\lfloor{#1}\right\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\bfloor}[1]{\bigg\lfloor{#1}\bigg\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\mag}  [1]{\left\vert\left\vert{#1}\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\bmag} [1]{\bigg\vert\bigg\vert{#1}\bigg\vert\bigg\vert}
 %
 \newcommand{\labelt}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\text{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\label} [2]{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}
 %
 \newcommand{\setcomp}[2]{\left\{{#1}~~\middle \vert~~ {#2}\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bsetcomp}[2]{\bigg\{{#1}~~\bigg \vert~~ {#2}\bigg\}}
 %
 \newcommand{\iint}[2]{\int {#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\dint}[4]{\int_{#3}^{#4}{#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\pred}[2]{\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}{#2}}#1}
 \newcommand{\ind} [2]{\frac{{\rm d} {#1}}{{\rm d}{#2}}}
 %
 \newcommand{\ii}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\ee}{{\rm e}}
 \newcommand{\exp}[1] { {\rm e}^{\large{#1}} }
 %
 \newcommand{\red}  [1]{\color{red}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\blue} [1]{\color{blue}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\green}[1]{\color{green}{#1}}
$Using idealized operational amplifiers (opamps), you can create idealized [integrating circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiator):

[image]

If the voltage $V_\text{in} - \text{Ground}$ is given by the function $V_\text{in}(t)$, and the output voltage $V_\text{out} - \text{Ground}$ is given by the function $V_\text{out}(t)$, then the circuit maintains:

$$V_\text{out}(t) = \dint{V_\text{in}(t')}{t'}{-\infty}{t}$$

as well as [integrating circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrator):

[image]

Similarly, if the voltage $V_\text{in} - \text{Ground}$ is given by the function $V_\text{in}(t)$, and the output voltage $V_\text{out} - \text{Ground}$ is given by the function $V_\text{out}(t)$, then the circuit maintains:

$$V_\text{out}(t) = \pred{V_\text{in}(t)}{t}$$

The main problem with this sort of "physics" approach to differential calculus is that the circuit components are idealized.  The opamps have their own power supply, so the calculation only works within a certain range.  The capacitors will explode if you try to push too much through them.

Also the differentiator circuit is very unreliable, any small white noise can cause large spikes (effectively a momentary [dirac delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) distribution) on the output.  But for your question, this might be a feature, since spikes would indicate discontinuity.

---

Both images are from wikimedia commons.

Comment: Didn't we have the [Analog computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer)
in the good old days ? I remember simulations of entire power plants on such
apparatus. Much faster than digital computers (and much less reliable too).

Comment: @HandeBruijn The term "computer" originally referred to humans who did computations for those who studied math.  A computer is nothing but the manifestation of human ability to predict results.  I guess that you could say that we've always had computers, even when using rocks to count the days.

Comment: An analog computer is not really a computer in the sense you describe. It's rather a simulation device based upon the fact that integration and differentiation can be mimicked with (non-digital) electronics, as you've described in the answer (+1).

Answer (score 4):

Soap films create a surface with minimal surface area naturally. [There is some more at this site](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/geometry/bubbles/bubbles.html). [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAyDi1aa40E). Note that these are local rather than global minima.

Comment: Yes minimal but not minimum.  James Grime made a video about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAyDi1aa40E

Comment: @DanielV I thought that was a useful addition so I've incorporated it in the answer.